# Sudoku solver generates cells with value 50+

Tags: c++

I wrote a code for solving sudoku puzzle, but im not getting expected result. my digits should be between 1 and 9, but in my output, it gets 50+ as well. I am putting my char values into vector, and im thinking that there may be a problem. i run program through to debugger and there are no any errors.

my code:

```
#include<string>
#include<list>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

#define N 9 



vector<char> getCandidates(int grid[N][N], int row, int col){

vector<char> result;

for (char c = '1'; c <= '9'; c++)
{
    
            bool collision = false;

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                if (grid[row][i] == c ||
                    grid[i][col] == c ||
                    grid[(row - row % 3) + i / 3][(col - col % 3) + i % 3] == c)
                {
                    collision = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!collision)
                result.emplace_back(c);
                 

         }

         return result;
    
}

bool Solve(int grid[N][N])
{

    bool solved = false;

    int row = -1;
    int col = -1;
    vector<char> candidates;
    candidates.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            if (grid[i][j] == 0)
            {
                vector<char> newCandidates = getCandidates(grid, i, j);
                if (row < 0 || newCandidates.size() < candidates.size())
                {
                    row = i;
                    col = j;
                    candidates = newCandidates;
                }
            }

    if (row < 0)
    {
        solved = true;
    }
    else
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < candidates.size(); i++)
        {
            grid[row][col] = candidates[i];
           
            if (Solve(grid))
            {
                solved = true;
                break;
            }
            grid[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }

    return solved;

}




void printGrid(int grid[N][N])
{
    for (int row = 0; row < N; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < N; col++)
            cout << grid[row][col] << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}


int main()
{

    int grid[N][N] = { { 3, 0, 6, 5, 0, 8, 4, 0, 0 },
                       { 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                       { 0, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1 },
                       { 0, 0, 3, 0, 1, 0, 0, 8, 0 },
                       { 9, 0, 0, 8, 6, 3, 0, 0, 5 },
                       { 0, 5, 0, 0, 9, 0, 6, 0, 0 },
                       { 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 5, 0 },
                       { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 4 },
                       { 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0 } };


    if (Solve(grid) == true)
        printGrid(grid);
    else
        cout << "No solution exists";

    return 0;
}
```

Output which I get:

```
3 49 6 5 50 8 4 51 52
5 2 51 52 54 55 49 50 53
50 8 7 49 51 53 54 3 1
52 51 3 50 1 49 53 8 54
9 54 50 8 6 3 51 49 5
53 5 49 51 9 52 6 55 50
1 3 52 54 49 50 2 5 51
49 53 54 55 52 51 50 7 4
51 50 5 2 53 6 3 52 49
```

Comment: `'1'` and `1` are two different things.

Comment: Tip: Don't use `#define` in C++, use `const`. You also don't need `if (x == true)`, you can just `if (x)`

Answer (score 2):

This loop:

```
for (char c = '1'; c <= '9'; c++)
```

is actually iterating from 49 to 57 (assuming an ASCII encoding), whereas `grid` contains `int`s from 1 to 9.

Just change the loop to:

```
for (int c = 1; c <= 9; c++)
```

Comment: @user4581301 Edited to mention this is ASCII. But still, you're probably right, I doubt anyone cares about EBCDIC ;)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're mixing up characters and their numeric code.

Have a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (it is also valid for other character encodings like ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8, at least for '1' through '9):

- '1' corresponds to value 49
- '2' corresponds to value 50
- ...
- '9' corresponds to value 57

Now, you need to decide whether you want:

- the grid to have values 1 through 9, in which case you use `for (int c = 1; c <= 9; c++)`, - but you'll need to ad a prefix when printing, i.e. something like `(char) ('0' + grid[col][row])`, or
- the grid to have characters '1' through '9', in which case you use `for (int c = '1'; c <= '9'; c++)`, and can just print it as-is (still casting to `char` though).